# Application of intermediate value theorem $f(k)=k$

Tags: calculus, limits

My textbook proposes this exercise

Let $f\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and such that, for all $x \in [0,1]$, $0 \le f(x) \le 1$. Prove that there is $k \in [0,1]$ such that $f(k)=k$.

We have that $0 \le f(x) \le 1$, then, by the intermediate value theorem, since $k \in [0,1]$, there is $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=k$.

However, I can't find how to make $c=k$.

Comment: Do you need strict proof? Or just logic about?

Comment: Try looking at the function $f(x) - x$ on the interval $[0,1]$. It's non-negative at $x=0$ and non-positive at $x=1$.

Comment: @EgorIvanov I'm trying to complete the proof. Actually, I don't even know if I did it the right way since I have not get to $f(k)=k$.

Comment: @RuanCarlos The comment above gives a good idea. Try to check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new function $g(x) = f(x) - x$. As $f$ is continuous, $g$ is also continuous.

Now, $g(0) = f(0) \geq 0$ and $g(1) = f(1) - 1 \leq 0$. So, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists a number $k\in [0,1]$ such that $g(k) = 0$, which implies that $f(k) = k$